# Top of Atmosphere of Landsat 8 bands

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

I am trying to calculate the Top of Atmoshpere using the corresponding coefficients. The raster calculator in ArcGIS however is giving me incorrect results. The formula I am using is `((0.00002 * .tif DN Band 4)-0.1)/0.5863`.

[image]

Comment: Have a look here (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#description) under _Code Editor (JavaScript)_. According to GEE the formila should be `band * 0.0000275 + (-0.2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments!

The formula is correct, but I was thrown off by the fact the max value exceeded 1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).